# Auto logon with logon screen

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer with Windows Authentication as external provider. It works perfectly: the logon screen displays the external provider button "Windows" and clicking on it logs me in without entering user and password.

I now would like to skip the logon dialog and directly execute the code that is run when clicking onto the "Windows" button.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Can you confirm or deny that when you click that button it's calling an action that calls `HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("Windows");` please?

Comment: Yes, it is calling Challenge(AccountOptions.WindowsAuthenticationSchemeName);

Comment: Meanwhile I solved my problem partially by setting AllowLocalLogin = false; in AccountOptions. Now I get directly logged on with windows credentials. What I still need is to have a way, e.g. by a URL query parameter to get back to login screen